# Delete action not working in Django rest framework tutorial 7 schemas and client libraries

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I followed the `Django rest framework` tutorial. I got an error on tutorial 7 while trying to delete the snippets through command line. I installed `coreapi` and `command line client`. But while I'm trying to delete a snippet using the command

```
$ coreapi action snippets delete --param id=7
```

I got the given below error

```
<Error: Forbidden>
    detail: "You do not have permission to perform this action."
```

And also `corejson` representation is not available as an option in GET request while visiting the API root endpoint in a browser.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are permissions added in tutorial 4. So you may need to [authenticate](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/7-schemas-and-client-libraries/#authenticating-our-client) with your coreapi client.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two solutions...

1.Comment the permission and authentication in `Settings.py` file or in your Viewsets (in case you have defined your permission in
    `views.py`).

2.Or you can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to authenticate yourself and then you may be able to delete

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the absence of `corejson` in `GET` request, it doesn't appear for me either. Only when I visit `schema` view (for instance `127.0.0.1:8000/schema`), that option appear. This makes sense, since `schema` display all schema API of the application.